# "unknown attribute" error in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have a class called `Appointment` that has, among other attributes, `start_time`.

In my form, I'm not using `start_time` directly. I'm separating it into `start_time_time` (I know it's an awkward name) and `start_time_ymd`. My goal is to combine `start_time_ymd` and `start_time_time` into a complete `start_time`. (I'm doing this because I don't like the UI for the helper that comes with a date field.)

The error I'm getting is `unknown attribute: start_time_time`, which is of course not surprising because `Appointment` doesn't have any attribute called `start_time_time`.

If `start_time_time` were something from a related model, I could just do something like `accepts_nested_attributes_for :whatever`, but since it's not, that wouldn't make sense.

How can I do what I'm trying to do? (I'm a Rails noob so you might have to spoon-feed it to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a [virtual attribute](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) ([text version](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes)) is your best bet.

Comment: Hmm, that certainly seems like the right idea, but they're not doing quite the same thing as me. They're combining two fields into one and I'm splitting one field into two. It's not possible, as far as I can think, to have to separate setters (`start_time_time` and `start_time_ymd`) set the value for one value (`start_time`). So I'm still unable to solve my problem.

Comment: Possibly important: I'm trying to instantiate my `Appointment` object by saying `@appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])`. Perhaps I'll have to instantiate a blank object and set each attribute individually in order for this solution to work.

Comment: If I set each attribute separately, it worked, and it didn't matter if I had any virtual attributes or not.

Comment: The real column is represented as a `DateTime` object, right?  Your virtual attributes can each set certain attributes on the `DateTime` and not run over each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in your model:

```
attr_accessible :start_time_time, :start_time_ymd
```

Comment: Nope: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible

Comment: Ah, seems like it was added in rails3. I'm using rails2 atm, and it didn't work.

Comment: (I think I was off in context of the question. — Would have to revisit it.)